# Secure exposure of services from a home NAS

Tags: server, security, nas

I have a machine running Ubuntu Server that acts like a NAS for local file storage.

I would now like to access it remotely as well as expose some services like FTP, chat and game servers to the internet.

How could I isolate and expose the services so there is little to no risk of unauthorized access to the rest of the server?

I've read about chrooting, LXC and Docker but I'm lost and not sure which of these approaches would be the most suitable.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

P.S: Saw the comments below which may or may not be from people that could potentially help. As I'm an advanced computer user that is mostly self-taught, I don't need a lenghthy howto and a short reply giving pointers is perfectly fine.

Comment: When you say “little to no risk”, what level of bad actor are you trying to keep out? If it’s just script kiddies, then follow standard practices of opening only the ports you need and using proper passwords/keys to allow access. If you want to keep intermediate-level attackers out, then you’ll want to either invest a lot of time in learning how system security works or use isolated servers for each purpose. There are no shortcuts if you are truly out for “little to no risk” 

Comment: "How do I set up a secure server" is too broad of a question for here.

Comment: @OrganicMarble can you suggest less broad subquestions that would fit the format?

Comment: @matigo I have no way to filter out who comes across the server so I probably should consider intermediate-level. Investing time is not a problem and I've done this already in spending a couple of weeks researching the subject but it's kind of silly to reinvent the wheel. So I am not looking for shortcuts but for pointers that you could perhaps offer?

Comment: @OrganicMarble this isn't about setting a secure server. You can rephrase it as asking how to set up a single service like FTP so it's secure since the procedure is probably the same for all of them. Hopefully, this clarifies things.

Comment: You might want to look into setting up an OpenVPN server on your NAS / Server so that when you VPN to it you should then have all functions available to it like FTP, etc without opening more than just port 1194 which is the default VPN port.  I followed but tweaked for my network the instructions that come along with the PiHole documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For a home user looking to experiment:

1. Check your router for a built-in VPN server. Some services (games) can be exposed to the internet via *port forwarding*, others (family photos, media server) keep tighter control over by limiting to LAN-only and VPN.

   - Use a hard password. You won't be entering it manually.
   - Your VPN Client is already built into NetworkManager.
   - A VPN server does not lock you into VPN-only access. It just means a lot fewer ports that need to be forwarded.
   - You can also use OpenVPN on your server, but the router might be easier to setup for your first try.
2. For actual applications and services, it's worthwhile to learn how to set up a container manager (LXD or Docker) so you can spin up experimental containers, and then throw them away when done. Containers also handle isolation quite well. I use LXD because it makes sense to me. Try both and see which makes sense to you.

   - It's worth an hour to follow a tutorial and set up *bridged networking* on your Ubuntu server. With a bridge, each container gets a separate LAN IP address from your router, and each container looks like a separate machine to your network. This doesn't work with many wireless chips, so cabled networking might be preferable. The initial setup is slightly more complex, but the setup of each container is slightly easier.
   - A nice feature of containers is that you can start/stop and freeze/unfreeze them. Your gameserver can be stopped during hours that it won't be used. While stopped or frozen, a vandal won't be able to connect.
3. Think security from the ground up. You already know that good security is a set of good habits, so start brushing your teeth now. SSH using keys only, always use complex passwords, keep good notes, keep track of your listening services and ports, etc. You already know the drill.
4. Focus on making your experiments *successful* rather than perfect the first time. The first time is NEVER perfect. (Just don't make them insecure!) Build your FTP or Game container, learn your lessons, write your notes...then delete the container and start over. It's fun and you will learn a lot.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful and thank you for the pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer from @user535733, but I'll just add an additional point:

5. *Limit external access in your firewall.* When doing port forwarding (for instance opening port 443 for external access to web services), check if your firewall supports limiting the IP-range for the access. I've done this for my own services, and I believe it's a good extra layer of security. The actual configuration will depend on your brand of firewall. For instance, the only IP adresses allowed for outside access to my services (without VPN access) are (mostly so I can access my own services from those locations):

   - My workplace
   - My parents
   - My trusted friends